# "Someone is sitting next to me." "Someone sits next to me."

Tags: difference, spoken-english

What is the difference between following sentences and more appropriate in a conversation.

> Someone is sitting next to me.
> Someone sits next to me.

Comment: The first describes that person's position relative to you. The second would usually be understood to mean that they come and sit down next to you. So it depends on what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, there aren't much differences between those 2.

However:

> Someone is sitting next to me.

Only means that someone is actually sitting close to you ("next to you").

While:

> Someone sits next to me.

Could means that someone is sitting next to you, someone is actually sitting (the time you are speaking) next to you or could also be a must for someone.